# How to insert in a user reputation (IPS 4.3)

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a shop and when buying reputation it creates another id

```
$q = Config::$g_con->prepare( 'INSERT INTO core_members (pp_reputation_points') VALUES (50)');
$q->execute(array($name_to_id));
```

[image]

Comment: That syntax is incorrect. I'm also not clear what your question is.

Comment: Remove the `'` from: `(pp_reputation_points')`

Comment: I deleted `'` but he don't add in me account but create another accounts with 50 reputation [link](https://i.imgur.com/SwhhIIb.png)

Comment: You are running an INSERT statement, this *creates* a record. If you want to modify a column in an existing record, you need an UPDATE statement. Is this what you are after ?

Comment: @GMB i using now code `UPDATE core_members SET pp_reputation_points = 50 WHERE member_id = ?` but don't add with my before reputation he set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments, I understand that you are looking to update the reputation of an existing user.

You need an UPDATE query (not an INSERT), as follows :

```
UPDATE core_members 
SET pp_reputation_points = pp_reputation_points + 50 
WHERE member_id = ?
```